# How to save values as an ArrayList of double in file

Tags: java

I want to save values as an ArrayList of double in a file. Whenever there is new value, it should be added in an ArrayList without erasing the previous ones. I'm try to use the function,DataStream. Is it possible? If its possible, please let me know how to implement that.

Comment: you should see java serialization, de-serialization

Comment: I'm not that familiar with java programming.. Can you give me some more detail?

Comment: For this kind of question, tell us what have you done so far is always a good idea

Comment: Is it a design goal for these files to be readable by humans and other non-Java applications? Will they be used in calculations after being read from the file? Do they represent decimal values (such as currency) or something truly floating point (such as coordinates in a 3d space)?

Comment: I'm making an android app. From the values in the file, it has to draw a line graph to show how the input values have changed. Those values will be 'weight'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer below code .

```
    private static String LFILE = "serial";

public static void updateFile(Double num) {

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

    try{
        List<Double> list = getDoubles();
        list.add(num);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(LFILE);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(list);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

public static List<Double> getDoubles() {

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    List<Double> newList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(LFILE);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        newList = (ArrayList<Double>) ois.readObject();

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        try {
            fis.close();
            ois.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return newList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

XStream is a library for Java which supports save/send objects in a xml-format. It is simple to use. XML is human readable making it easy to check its corrent or modify.

Answer (score 0):

The class you want to use are ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream

e.g.
http://www.javadb.com/writing-objects-to-file-with-objectoutputstream

http://www.javadb.com/reading-objects-from-file-using-objectinputstream